# Send Option Value to a global variable on view

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-select

Im trying to send the value of a dropdown list on my javascript to a variable in the same view, the purpouse is that i would like to use the value of the selected option to make a if statement inside another dropdown option and i dont know any other way for doing this

This is my JavaScript

```js
$('#sel0').on('change', function () {
                       dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();
                       date = $(this).val();
                      
                   });
```

This is the variable on my view:

```
@{
var Date = "";
}
```

This is my dropdownlist wich i want to take the selected value:

```html
  <select  id="sel0">
     <option value="">Todos</option>

          @foreach (var item in Model.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
               {
               <option value="@lines">@lines</option>
          
              }
     </select>
```

I want to be able to make a Input of the sum Values of my list based on the date that i take from my dropdown list selected value, Ex: is user pics 1 date from my dropdown list i shoul be able to take that value and make a sum in a foreach statement of my list and create a input with the result something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Date == this.Date)//date is the value i took from the user select option
            .Select(x =>
                {
                Rid = x.Rid,
               Total = x.Total
                 })
                 .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                  .Select(z => new
                  {
                  Turno = z.Key,
Total = Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0)
                  }))
                  {
                  <input value="@item)" />
                   }
```

Any help will be appreciated i dont know any other way of doing this

Comment: your C# code executes on server before your js code at client

Comment: i know thats why i asked if someone knows a better way of doing this of if it exists a wa to do this

Answer (score 0):

The ways executing server code once view is rendered in browser are:

1. Form post, make your calcs, re-render the view
2. Make Ajax call to an action method, pass your selected date as data, process your logic in the action method and return result. On success draw your input (or fill it's value) with response received.

Look for examples of the option you need there are lots.

Answer (score 0):

the C# code in your razor view executes on server and produces the markup and will be returned the browser. Your client side js code on the select element change event happens way later at the client side. The value from your selected option cannot be used to execute some code in your razor again.

You have 2 options.

**Page reload with querystring value of selected option**

When user selects a date, Reload the page and pass the selected item as the querystring. This means you need to update your current GET action method to accept this param value and then you will use this value to do your filter.

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date)
{
   YourViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
   if(date!=null)
   {
     //Do your filtering based on the date.Value.
   }
   return View(vm);
}
```

And when user changes the dropdown, reload the page with the selection option value;

```
$('#sel0').on('change', function () {
   window.location.href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")?date="+$(this).val();
});
```

**Ajax**

You may make an ajax call to the server where you execcute your filter and return the partial view back and inject that to the DOM

```
$('#sel0').on('change', function () {
   $("#InputContainer").load("@Url.Action("GetDynamicInputs","Home")?date="+$(this).val());
});
```

Now make sure that in your main page you have a container div (to which we will load the dynamic number of inputs) with Id `InputContainer`

And have an action method to accept the date and return a partial view using your filter based on the passed date value

```
public ActionResult GetDynamicInputs(DateTime date)
{
  //use the date to determine the markup you want return from your partial view
  return PartialView();
}
```